# Ajax infinite scroll down pagination . image not showing while using async in ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, infinite-scroll

I am using ajax to load data when user scroll further down the page . i am using `async = false;` which will stop the calls to the ajax function unless the already running call is completed. Yes , its not recommended to use async. but to prevent data disorder i have to use it.
Here is my `ajax function`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var page = 1;
   var busy = false; 

   var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop)
   {
       if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()-550 && busy == false)
        {
           loadMoreData(page);
           page++;
       }

   }

   lastScrollTop = st;
});



   function loadMoreData(page){

     $.ajax(
           {
               type: "POST",
               url: '<?php echo base_url('sura/load_verse/'.$sura_id.'/')?>'+page,
               async: false,
               cache: false,
               beforeSend: function()
               {
                   $('#loader_message').show();
               }
           })
           .done(function(data)
           {
               if(data == ""){
                  $('.ajax-load').html("No More Data Found");
                   return;
               }
               $('.ajax-load').hide();
               $("#post-data").append(data);
           })
           .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
           {

           });

            busy = false;
            $('#loader_message').hide();
   }
</script>
```

but the async call does not let the browser to show my loading image `$('#loader_message').show();` while the call is fetching the data. 
can somebody help me in showing the image while using the async call .Or is there an alternative for async which will stop multiple request at the same time.
Thanks

Comment: we need some real life example to be able to reproduce the problem... in normal circumstances it should load images normally... check [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/8juugnjz/1)

Comment: You dont have to use async at all. It's just the easiest way to go. Thousands of sites worked around these issues and a recommended way

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is to show the loader before starting the ajax call. `beforeSend` doesn't work because the DOM is not modified until after `$.ajax()` is done and `show`ing the loader qualifies as modifying the DOM.

Below is my suggested solution. I changed your code a bit to use what I feel are "best practices" for javascript. One thing I always avoid is using PHP code inside the javascript. What you do with `base_url()` will become a problem if you move your javascript to an external file. That is why I usually define a `var baseURL` as shown below.

I also cache any JQuery object that needs to be created more than once which is why the vars `thisWindow` and `loader` were added.

It also appears that once you set `busy = true` it is never changed back to `false`. That is remedied by adding an `.always` call which runs `busy=false`. The loader is also hidden in `.always` so that you can be certain it will removed even if there is an ajax `.fail`.

I think that with `busy` being properly managed you can use `async: true,`. I strongly recommend you give that a try.

Here's my answer

```
<script>
var page = 1;
var busy = false;
var baseURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var thisWindow = $(window);
var loader = $('.ajax-load');

thisWindow.scroll(function (event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop)
    {
        //check busy first, if busy=true you avoid making calls
        //do scrollTop() and height()
        if (busy == false && thisWindow.scrollTop() + thisWindow.height() > $(document).height() - 550)
        {
            loadMoreData(page);
            page++;
        }

    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
});


function loadMoreData(page) {
    busy = true;
    loader.show();

    $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: baseURL + "/sura/load_verse/$sura_id/" + page,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
            })
            .done(function (data)
            {
                if (data == "") {
                    loader.html("No More Data Found");
                    return;
                }
                $("#post-data").append(data);
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {

            })
            .always(function () {
                busy = false;
                loader.hide();
            });

}
</script>
```